# Ansible - User input

Tags: ansible, f5

If a user is prompted for some input and in this case they don't input anything and just press enter a " '' " value is put into the variable:

Example of the question:

```
- name: "vs_rule"
  prompt: "enter the associated rule [Press enter to skip or enter in the following format: rule1 rule2]"
  private: no
```

I'd like to use something similar to the below code but I don't want to pass the quotes onto the LTM (''), since the user will see the following error: `"std exception: (basic_string::substr), exiting..."`

Is there a way to filter the '' after the else and just send nothing to the LTM?

```
- "{{ 'tmsh list ltm rule ' + vs_rule + '' if vs_rule else '' |default([]) }}"
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the `vars_prompt` documentation ([here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html)), you can add a default value for your variable, in the case the user does not enter any content.

On your case you could pass an empty string:

```
- name: "vs_rule"
  prompt: "enter the associated rule [Press enter to skip or enter in the following format: rule1 rule2]"
  private: no
  default: ""
```

and the remaining "code" will work

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave that a try, and it still passes on the quotes to the LTM. I'll keep looking around, but let me know if you think of another way around it.